# exported pdf file using dataExporter from datatable having messages from properties file in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

[image]

I have one datatable in which we are showing some details. We have some name, category, and description(message). I am using .properties file for messages. And in properties file I used placeholder for dynamic name and values. But when I exported that datatable data using dataExporter, I'm getting the description as shown belowe. Means getting {1},{0} for place holder